# Node-csv-npm install causes Meteor to hang at "Starting your app..."

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I created a new meteor app using meteor create, including bootstrap and coffeescript.

**Then I added the following packages:**

- sudo npm install -g meteorite
- mrt add filepicker
- sudo mrt add xml2js

*All is well at this point.  I can start the app and see Hello World just fine.*

**Then I try to add the csv package:**

- sudo mrt add node-csv-npm

Install goes well, but when I go to start the app, in the terminal, it hangs at "Starting your app."

Open to any ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why are you running the `mrt add` commands as root?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I think I ended up doing that since I got errors without it.  I can create a new app and try again without the sudo and see if it changes the situation.

Comment: @DavidWeldon - Created a new app.  Did not use sudo.  Same issue.

Comment: Huh, I don't know. It works fine for me with meteor v0.7.1.2 and mrt v0.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tied to the `node-csv-npm` package, I had the problem with another one that was working great an hour ago, but needed to be re-added due to branch merging. Unfortunately, the only solution I've found is a brutal one:

- Remove all traces to the package from `packages` folder, `smart.json`, `smart.lock` and `packages/.gitignore` to be sure.
- After that, manually add `package/packagename` folder with source of the package.